# Cannot find module vueform.config

Tags: typescript, vue.js, config

I'm trying to use Vueforms for my project but I just copy pasted their installation code in my `.ts` and `.js` files but I'm getting errors when I try to import vueformconfig and builderconfig

Here's my `main.ts` file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vueform from '@vueform/vueform'
import vueformConfig from './../vueform.config'
import Builder from '@vueform/builder'
import builderConfig from './../builder.config'


const app = createApp(App)
app.use(Vueform, vueformConfig)
app.use(Builder, builderConfig)
app.mount('#app')
```

Here is the error message from Typescript transpiler:

```
src/main.ts:5:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './../vueform.config' or its corresponding type declarations.


src/main.ts:7:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './../builder.config' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I've surfed many sites and forums for a fix but I can't find any and I'm kind of stuck here

**Edit:**

I'm using Vite+Vue as my build tool and I'm supposed to use `main.ts` as a file to create a vue app and call required imports like vueformconfig and builderconfig

**Edit 2:**

I tried changing the import statement of `vueform.config` to `vueform.config.ts` and did the same with `builder.config`

```
import vueformConfig from './../vueform.config.ts'
import builderConfig from './../builder.config.ts'
```

That seemed to have fixed the issues with the import statement but I get errors at the `app.use()` lines.

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(Vueform, vueformConfig) //error1
app.use(Builder, builderConfig) //error2
app.mount('#app')
```

Error Message:

```
src/main.ts:11:9 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(plugin: Plugin<[any]>, options_0: any): App<Element>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import("C:/Users/aryan/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/spacious-forms/node_modules/@vueform/vueform/types/index")' is not assignable to parameter of 
type 'Plugin<[any]>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(plugin: Plugin<any>, options: any): App<Element>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import("C:/Users/aryan/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/spacious-forms/node_modules/@vueform/vueform/types/index")' is not assignable to parameter of 
type 'Plugin<any>'.

11 app.use(Vueform, vueformConfig)
           ~~~~~~~


src/main.ts:12:9 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(plugin: Plugin<[BuilderConfig]>, options_0: BuilderConfig): App<Element>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import("C:/Users/aryan/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/spacious-forms/node_modules/@vueform/builder/index")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<[BuilderConfig]>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(plugin: Plugin<BuilderConfig>, options: BuilderConfig): App<Element>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof import("C:/Users/aryan/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/spacious-forms/node_modules/@vueform/builder/index")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<BuilderConfig>'.

12 app.use(Builder, builderConfig)
           ~~~~~~~
```

**Edit 2:**
As another person asked for the project structure, here it is

```
spacious-forms
|
|____vueform.config.ts
|
|____builder.config.ts
|
|____src
|    |
|    |__ main.ts
```

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . ".ts and .js" - which js? There are generally supposed to be no .js files in TS project, unless they are paired with .d.ts. What is "'./../"? main.ts is supposed to be at the source root, and importing files outside it may result in problems

Comment: I'm using Vue js with vite and I'm required to import vueformconfig and builderconfig in my `main.ts` file which vue uses as an entry point. The `main.ts` file is within the specified vue project folder

Comment: It just seems your `main.ts` file location doesn't have the `.config` files in the parent forder. Are they where you want to import them ?

Comment: The installation tutorial of vueform told me to create `vueform.config.ts` file but in the `main.js` , they only called `vueform.config`. I did change the import statement to `vueform.config.ts` but I get an operator error.

Comment: I mean that you shouldn't locate source files outside /src/, and you don't need to use .js in TS project unless there's a reason to do this

Comment: I managed to fix the import error but now i get overload error at `app.use()` statements

Comment: Sorry but could you share your project structure ? Where the vueform.config.ts and builder.config.ts files are located regarding your main.ts

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens Updated the question with the project structure, check it out

Comment: Thanks. Did you try removing `./` part to only have `import vueformConfig from '../vueform.config'`

Answer (score 0):

try to import files like this:

```
import vueformConfig from '../vueform.config.ts'
import builderConfig from '../builder.config.ts'
```